# Sequence of functions converges to a uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

This is a problem from Abbott's Analysis:

Let $f$ be uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$, and define a sequence of functions $f_n(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{n})$. Show that $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly. Give an example to show that this proposition fails if $f$ is only assumed to be continuous and not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know I want $|f(x+1/n)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. I am struggling with finding an $N$ so I can manipulate the quantity on the left to get eventually to epsilon.

Comment: Write down the definition of uniform continuity in $\epsilon$-$\delta$ language. Then you choose $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \delta$.

Comment: Ok, so I see why you chose N like that but I don't know how to replace the 1/n inside of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the proof, given $\epsilon > 0$, since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon, \forall x, y \text{ such that } |x - y| < \delta. \tag{$*$}$$
Now let $N$ be chosen such that $\frac{1}{N} < \delta$ (notice that the choice of $N$ doesn't depend on $x$). Then for all $n > N$, by $(*)$ it follows that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |f(x + 1/n) - f(x)| < \epsilon,$$
since $|x + 1/n - x| = 1/n < 1/N < \delta$. That is, $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly.

---

One counterexample: $f(x) = x^2, x \in \mathbb{R}$. It can be seen that
\begin{align*}
& \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left[\left(x + \frac{1}{n}\right)^2 - x^2\right] \\
= & \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left[\frac{2}{n}x + \frac{1}{n^2}\right] \\
\geq & \frac{2}{n}\times n + \frac{1}{n^2} \\
= & 2 + \frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align*}
which doesn't converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

It goes like this:

By uniform continuity of $f$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such that 
$$
|x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow
|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon,
$$
namely such that 
$$
x + \frac{1}{n} - x = \frac{1}{n} < \delta \Rightarrow
\bigg| f\bigg( x+\frac{1}{n} \bigg) - f(x) \bigg| < \varepsilon,
$$ 
namely such that 
$$
n > 1/\delta \Rightarrow
\bigg| f\bigg( x + \frac{1}{n} \bigg) - f(x) \bigg| < \varepsilon.
$$